# Parallel processing and generators — can get broken?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, generator

I'm having a hard time with this, lets think, I have a generator, and I want to run it a function over every element of it and store the values, but here is the points:

1. we made a generator
2. we use parallel process to run over 2 cores
3. the first element, call the generator
4. the second element, call the generator, but is secure this run of the generator, if the first execution still did't finish?

The hard part here is how to call the generator one by one in multiproccesing in a safe way, this happens specially when the function to generate takes some time, in that case would be ideal can run the generator in multiprocessing too, and when a value is ready, go to the next section of the code.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generator():
 i = 0
 while 1:
  if i > 20:
   break
  i = i + 1
  time.sleep(1)
  yield i

def n(x):
 return x

g = generator()
d = []

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
 d = pool.map(n, g)

>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

All seems to work fine, my question there is..., will always works fine? or there will come the time where this will be broken?

I'm not satisfied with "how works now, will works later, how we tested it a lot now, it will works later"

Comment: Although you create a process pool, but you never use it

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in parallel or across processes here. As Jacky stated, you're not using the multi process pool at all. But if you did correct the code to perform the idea I believe you meant to express, you should not expect the same/safe results.

Comment: ups, fixing fixing

Comment: fixed, is there a way to do this..., clean and safe?, I still get the same result

Comment: Do not expect any speed up since the inter-process communication (IPC) and the creation of new objects will likely be much slower than the current computation.

Comment: This is just an example, to be practical I will use a code that takes more time to execute....